# Can't run su after changing permissions to su file

Tags: permissions, sudo, su

I am running Linux Slackware 14.0. I wanted to allow to do `su` only to the members of wheel group, so I modified the permissions of `/bin/su` and `/usr/bin/sudo` files to this:

```
bash-4.2# ls -la /bin/su
-rws--s--- 1 root wheel 59930 Sep 14  2012 ./su

bash-4.2# ls -la ./sudo
-rws--s--- 1 root wheel 107220 Jun 29 2012 ./sudo
```

Now when I am a member of wheel group and run `su`, it promts for password, I enter it. No errors are shown, but doesn't switch me to root. Probably, I set some permissions wrong?

Comment: Group is missing `read` access, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
chown root.wheel /bin/su
chmod o-x /bin/su
```

so `su` will belong to `wheel` group and the `others` won't be able to run it. It seems to me that `chown` should solve your problem, setting properly all the permissions, since you just set up the execution rights previously.

Answer (score 0):

No need to modify the permissions of `su` or `sudo`.

this kind of config is done in /etc/sudoers, you must edit it with `visudo`.

Comment: `su` does not read configuration from `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: It seems kinda pointless to change the behaviour of `su` though... it requires the password of the user you want to become so it's not really different from just logging in directly as this user. Screwing with the permissions could very well break programs that rely on `su` or `sudo` to work properly.